# Remove null values from html css tags in shiny

Tags: html, css, r, shiny

I have a simple shiny application where in when you click on the plus sign, the drop down appears.That is fine. (This is a rough table. Do not worry)

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("ry")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$ry <- renderDataTable({
    
    
    callback <- paste0("
        table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
                                      var format = function(d) {
                                      return '<body><div style=\"background-color:#cbe6ef; padding: .5em;text-align:center;\"><table><tr><td><b>Tag</b></td><td><b>Number of Reviews</b></td><td><b> Share of Reviews </b></td><td><b> Click for Reviews </b></td> <tr><td> null </td><td>' + d[50] + '</td><td>' + d[51] + '</td><td>' + d[52] + '</td></tr> <tr><td>' + d[45] + '</td><td>' + d[46] + '</td><td>' + d[47] + '</td><td>' + d[48] + '</td></tr> <tr><td>' + d[41] +'</td></tr> </tr></table></div></body>';};
                                      table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                                      var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                                      if (row.child.isShown()) {
                                      row.child.hide();
                                      td.html('&plus;');
                                      } else {
                                      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                                      td.html('&minus;');
                                      }
                                      });")
    
    
    datatable(cbind(Plus = '&plus;',iris),
              escape = F,
              rownames = F,options = list(                  columnDefs = list(
                list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = c(0))
              )),
              callback = JS(callback
              ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

But as you can see there are null values here. So when there are null values , that entire row should get removed. So I tried with below stuffs but not working

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  dataTableOutput("ry")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$ry <- renderDataTable({
    
    
    callback <- paste0("
        table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
                                      var format = function(d) {
                                      return '<body><div style=\"background-color:#cbe6ef; padding: .5em;text-align:center;\"><table><tr><td><b>Tag</b></td><td><b>Number of Reviews</b></td><td><b> Share of Reviews </b></td><td><b> Click for Reviews </b></td> <tr><td> null </td><td>' + d[50] + '</td><td>' + d[51] + '</td><td>' + d[52] + '</td></tr> <tr><td>' + d[45] + '</td><td>' + d[46] + '</td><td>' + d[47] + '</td><td>' + d[48] + '</td></tr> <tr><td>' + d[41] +'</td></tr> </tr></table></div><script type='text/javascript'> document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach((item) => {if (item.textContent.includes('null')) {item.parentElement.remove();}});</script></body>';};
                                      table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
                                      var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
                                      if (row.child.isShown()) {
                                      row.child.hide();
                                      td.html('&plus;');
                                      } else {
                                      row.child(format(row.data())).show();
                                      td.html('&minus;');
                                      }
                                      });")
    
    
    datatable(cbind(Plus = '&plus;',iris),
              escape = F,
              rownames = F,options = list(                  columnDefs = list(
                list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = c(0))
              )),
              callback = JS(callback
              ))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Can anyone help me here please. Also my intent is make it dynamic. I mean the null value in html should not be changed. So we need to check if the table has null rows or not. If yes, then remove entire row or else keep it

Comment: I Had tagged it :)

Comment: where are  null values? I see only one in the left upper cell in column "tag". Can you explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: When you click on plus sign :)

Comment: Hi. Did you get a chance to solve this :) I still did not get it

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Thus, I can't help.

Comment: When you click on the plus sign, a drop down appears right? In that drop down there are null values. So is there a way to remove the row that are having null values? Makes sense :) ?